# Why is Display Name is not Showing in Calendar Event Attendees?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm successfully retrieving Calendar Event Attendees using the following code gist:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=" .  __DIR__ . '/mt-service-account.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName("APP NAME");
$client->setSubject("<APPROPRIATE_USER_EMAIL>");
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
]);

$calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$optParams = array(
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'orderBy'      => 'startTime'
);
$events = $calendarService->events->listEvents('<APPROPRIATE_CALENDAR_ID>', $optParams);

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
  print_r($event->getAttendees());
}
```

However, as can be seen in the response, no Display Name is returned.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee Object
        (
            [additionalGuests] => 
            [comment] => 
            [displayName] => 
            [email] => johnsmith@domain.com
            [id] => 
            [optional] => 
            [organizer] => 
            [resource] => 
            [responseStatus] => needsAction
            [self] => 
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )
)
```

The attendee in question is a Contact of the event creator and the Contact's name and email appear in the type assist field when creating an event.

**UPDATE** **NB** Events are not created via API. They're created via Google Calendar (i.e. in browser). The attendees are added by typing the attendee's name in the Add Attendee field (Google type-assist found the Contact). The aim is to retrieve programmatically (i.e. with API) event details created by our G Suite Calendar users

Comment: 4 years later, I have the same problem. Did you figure this out @Jordan?

Answer (score 1):

I cant see how you are creating the event in question but my guess is that when the event was created and the attendee added their display name was not inserted as an optional parameter.

[Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

> attendees[].displayName   string  The attendee's name, if available. Optional.    writable

When events are creted via the Google Calendar web view you just add a users Email address.  In the event that said user is a Gmail account then Google can guess the display name.   In the event it is not a Gmail account then google has no way of knowing what the users name is there for you end up with a display name of null.

```
attendees": [
    {
     "email": "lme@gmail.com",
     "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
     "organizer": true,
     "self": true,
     "responseStatus": "accepted"
    },
    {
     "email": "ll@meAtWork.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
```

Comment: @DalmTo The event was not created via API. It was created via Google Calendar (i.e. in browser). The attendee was added by typing the attendee's name in the Add Attendee form (Google type assists found the Contact). My aim is to retrieve programmatically (i.e. with API) event details created by our G Suite Calendar users

Comment: Display name is only added via the web view if it is a gmail account and google has some way of knowing what the users name is.   This might also work if the user organizer has said user in their google contacts google might be able to grab it that way as well.

Comment: @DalmTo This seems strange as it does appear that Google does have a way of knowing what the user's name is. To reproduce the issue: 
1) Create a non-Google contact in G Suite "Contacts" view (ex. John Smith w/ email johnsmith@domain.com)
2) In G Suite Calendar web view, create an event on your calendar and in Attendees field, start typing "John Smith". You'll see Google will complete the name (thus suggesting to me that Google has knowledge of the user's name)

Comment: I don't have access to G Suite your going to have to test it but basically if the value isn't being returned by the API its because it wasn't inserted at the time the user was added.    G Suite is new and may not be fully integrated into all of Googles offerings like calendar.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you. It is bit disheartening. G Suite I would think is not that new. It's just a renaming of Google Apps for Your Domain and Googles Apps for Work which has been around since 2006. BTW, I have followed you on Twitter :-)

Comment: I don't have access to apps for work either :)  Lets change the previous statement and say that Google calendar is old and really could use an update to support the newer stuff.  If you can figure out how adding a feature request to G Suite might be a good idea.