# Missing meeting organizer display name when getting events from Google Calendar API v3

Tags: google-calendar-api

When querying events via the Google Calendar API (V3), I am unable to see the display name of the organizer of the event. The email field is populated however there is no display name.

From previous research I can only find mentions that in order to get the display name to populate, the GSuite user must also activate Google+ on the user's account. Is this seriously the only way to do it? Or are there any other API calls I can use to maybe retrieve this data?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I see the same thing here in 2023, and the linked answer makes very little sense. An event created via Google Calendar webpage, by a user within the GWS tenant, is lacking `organizer.displayName` when fetched via the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Daimto's answer** from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065049/why-is-display-name-is-not-showing-in-calendar-event-attendees).

> **Display name** is only added via the web view if it is a gmail account
>   and google has some way of knowing what the users name is. This might
>   also work if the user organizer has said user in their google contacts
>   google might be able to grab it that way as well.